# node how to run a Interactivity script( python, shell , etc..)

Tags: node.js

I have a python Interactivity script, like following example:

```
$ python sync_email.py

please input your email: myemail@email.com

  validating...

please input your password: 

  password correct.

Now will sync the email to local...
```

I want to use node to run the python script, and auto enter the email and password.

actually I want to batch execute python script with different email in no-block IO. how to do that?

Comment: can you modify the sync_email script to just accept it's users via the command line?  else this might be of use some use  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649891/node-js-sending-key-shortcuts-to-child-process

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=expect

Answer (score 13):

The answer to your Problem could be Python-Shell,
Install with npm.
https://www.npmjs.org/package/python-shell

To Send data to Python script(writes in stdin):

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell'); 
var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');    
// sends a message to the Python script via stdin
pyshell.send('hello');
```

To Recieve from Python script(just use print in python):

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell'); 
var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) { 
// received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)  
console.log(message); });
```

Verry easy to use, but note that you might specefy parameters/the path to the script so you have to use it like this.

```
var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  scriptPath: '/absolute/path/to/my/scripts',
  args: ['param1', 'value1', 'param2', 'value2']
};
var pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py',options);
```

Maybe its to late for your purpose but it might help others since i had the same problem and it took me some time ;)

Comment: Great answer. 
BTW how do I receive my arguments in my python script?

Comment: @QuikProBroNa I usually did scan Stdin for input constantly ->                                                   while True:
 userinput = stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')