# Run interactive script with node, let user interact with it, go back to node script when done

Tags: node.js, shell

I would like to run a program from my node app and let users interact with it.
The purpose is a server management node script. When I type `naps dbadmin gigsnet`, I want node to run `mongo` putting all of the right parameters in (user, database, etc.).

This is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432188/node-how-to-run-a-interactivity-script-python-shell-etc), since I want the user to actually freely interact with the mongo shell -- a bit like it happens when you run a program from a bash script.

Am I missing something totally simple?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: Yep, adding it here now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
var db = 'someDatabase'
var user = 'someUser'
var pass = 'somePassword'
spawn('mongo', ['-u', user, '-p', password, '--authenticationDatabase', 'admin', db ], {stdio: 'inherit', shell: true})
```

This worked well for me. It was a bit of trial-end-error to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to take a look right [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-run-cmd)

**node-run-cmd** seems to run command line so it could be your solution